# Audio Recode during sleep - Android

Tags: android, android-audiorecord

I am making some app using AudioRecord class in Android.
Someone might have already asked the same question.. But, I appreciate any insight.

I am recording "voice" like the following:

```
recorder.startRecording();
Thread.sleep(10000);
recorder.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
recorder.stop();
```

"recorder" is an instance of "AudioRecord" class.

I can get data with this code, but, I am not sure if the data collected by this way is reliable.

My intention of this code is to stop the program & record voice for 10 seconds.

So, the question is if this approach can get the correct voice data?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

When using `AudioRecord`, you need to call `read` constantly in order to drain the filling recording buffer.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html#read(byte[], int, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html#read%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29)

If you don't read, the buffer can get overrun, and then you'll lose your voice data.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Ok. I want to clarify. I edit my question. And, in my current codes, after "Thread.sleep(10000);", I make the program read the data by "recorder.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);". You mean this is not correct? Ok. Anyway, I will read that document. Thank you!

Comment: It's not correct, because during your 10 second delay, the recorder already dumps a lot of data because you didn't read it. Recording needs to be a real-time, high-priority operation, otherwise the internal buffer won't keep your data.